# Where to download old red5 releases

Tags: red5

I'm trying to install the 0.9.1 relaese of red5 server.

In the  official red5 githib page the link is http://red5.org/downloads/red5/0_9/red5-0.9.0.zip

But this link is not working ; red5.org is down.

Thank you a lot in advance for any help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a download link http://en.osdn.jp/projects/sfnet_webconfo/downloads/red5-0.9.1.tar.gz/ . (Maybe will get missing in the future).

As stated on their github: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/blob/master/README.md#previous-releases .

> The artifacts for the following releases are no longer available; if
>   your project requires them, you'll have to build them from source. The
>   listings are here only for historical purposes.
>
> Build from Source
>
> To build the red5 jars, execute the following on the command line:
>
> mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
>
> This will create the jars in the "target" directory of the workspace;
>   this will also skip the unit tests.
>
> To package everything up in an assembly (tarball/zip):
>
> mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package -P assemble
>
> To build a milestone tarball:
>
> mvn -Dmilestone.version=1.0.7-M1 clean package -Pmilestone

I put here the instruction in case their github gets deleted or the website goes missing.